# swift, tableView selectedTypes buttons

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift3

i need an help, see this class

```
import UIKit

protocol TypesTableViewControllerDelegate: class {
  func typesController(controller: TypesTableViewController, didSelectTypes types: [String])
}

class TypesTableViewController: UITableViewController {

  let possibleTypesDictionary = ["bakery":"Bakery", "bar":"Bar", "cafe":"Cafe", "grocery_or_supermarket":"Supermarket", "restaurant":"Restaurant"]
  var selectedTypes: [String]!
  weak var delegate: TypesTableViewControllerDelegate!
  var sortedKeys: [String] {
    return possibleTypesDictionary.keys.sort()
  }

  // MARK: - Actions
  @IBAction func donePressed(sender: AnyObject) {
    delegate?.typesController(self, didSelectTypes: selectedTypes)
  }

  // MARK: - Table view data source
  override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return possibleTypesDictionary.count
  }

  override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("TypeCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) 
    let key = sortedKeys[indexPath.row]
    let type = possibleTypesDictionary[key]!
    cell.textLabel?.text = type
    cell.imageView?.image = UIImage(named: key)
    cell.accessoryType = (selectedTypes!).contains(key) ? .Checkmark : .None
    return cell
  }

  // MARK: - Table view delegate
  override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)
    let key = sortedKeys[indexPath.row]
    if (selectedTypes!).contains(key) {
      selectedTypes = selectedTypes.filter({$0 != key})
    } else {
      selectedTypes.append(key)
    }

    tableView.reloadData()
  }
}
```

here the user can tap a cell of the tableView so that his prefer types are used on the next viewController for a search, now i need to build a class that do the same thing but there is no a tableview rather only 6 buttons in a view that the user can tap (so a viewController with only 6 different buttons to tap). The problem is that i don't know how to pass to the next viewController what buttons have been pressed and what are not, how can i build this class?

here is the function in the other class that need to know what buttons have been pressed

```
func fetchNearbyPlaces(coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D) {

        mapView.clear()

        dataProvider.fetchPlacesNearCoordinate(coordinate, radius:searchRadius, types: searchedTypes) { places in
            for place: GooglePlace in places {

                let marker = PlaceMarker(place: place)

                marker.map = self.mapView
```

where is "types: serchedTypes"

Answer (score 0):

What you wanna do is called **delegation** here is how you do it:

1. Make a **protocol** like this one:

   ```
   protocol  TransferProtocol : class
   {
       func transferData(types:[String])
   }
   ```
2. Make the view controller with the buttons **conform** to that protocol, I like to do it by adding extensions to my classes like so:

   ```
   extension ButtonsViewController:TransferProtocol{
     func transferData(types:[String]){
     //Do whatever you want here
     }
   }
   ```
3. Declare a variable in your Table View Controller class with the protocol you created as its type, this is called a **delegate**

   ```
   weak var transferDelegate:TransferProtocol?
   ```
4. Before you **segue** to the Buttons View Controller you want to set that view controller as the **delegate** you just created like so:

   ```
   override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
       let vc = segue.destination as? ButtonsViewController
       transferDelegate = vc
       vc?.transferData(types: selected)

   }
   ```

If done correctly you should be able to work with the array you built in the Table View Controller(TypesTableViewController)